# Unexplained formatting of HTML created using Knitr/R Markdown with xtable and raw HTML tables

Tags: r, knitr, xtable, r-markdown

Following an xtable by a raw HTML table causes paragraph formatting of the lines between the xtable and the raw HTML table to format unexpectably, as shown in following image:
[image]

Paragraphs are no longer displayed as paragraphs and heading 3 (If you remove this html table, the formatting is correct)  is no longer treated as a header.

The following code contains the contents of the .RMD file - could you please let me know if you spot any errors in my code, or what the required work around is?

Thanks.

````
Printing xtable followed by HTML table 
=================================

### Heading 3

paragraph 1

paragraph 2

```{r displayProductionDataSources, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
require(xtable)
print(xtable(data.frame(Temp=mean(airquality$Temp))), type = "html", include.rownames = FALSE)
```

paragraph 3

paragraph 4



### If you remove this html table, the formatting is correct
<table>
    <tr align="left">
      <th>Dataframe</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Variables</th>
    </tr>
</table>
````

**sessionInfo():**
[image]

Comment: Works ok for me. I suggest to first update all packages and post sessionInfo() after retry/updating. Also make there are no hidden space-lookalikes in the file.

Comment: @DieterMenne I had also checked this on my colleague's computer and the same problem occurred.  I have added sessionInfo() to the original posting.

Comment: I have found a work-around - which is to wrap the displayProductionDataSources chunk in a HTML paragraph, i.e. to place <p> and </p> before and after the chunk, respectively.  I would, however, like to know why I need this workaround and, e.g., Dieter Menne doesn't!

Comment: What versions of `Rstudio` are you using?

Comment: @mnel: I am using RStudio Version 0.98.484

Comment: It appears to work for me with Rstudio 0.98.692

Comment: Mine is .807 (daily build)